# how to filter facet to show only specific terms

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

I want a facet to only show specific terms. I've tried both a filter and a `facet_filter` of type `terms`, but both show other terms different from the given in the `terms` filter.

**As filter**

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "filter": {
                "terms": { "text": [ "bogota", "antioquia", "medellin", "cali", "barranquilla", "bucaramanga", "cucuta", "pasto", "manizales", "caldas", "santander" ] }
            }
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "dictionary": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "text",
                "size": "10"
            },
        }
    }
};
```

**As facet filter**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "terms": { "text": [ "bogota", "antioquia", "medellin", "cali", "barranquilla", "bucaramanga", "cucuta", "pasto", "manizales", "caldas", "santander" ] }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "dictionary" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "text"
            },
            "facet_filter": {
                "terms": { "text": [ "bogota", "antioquia", "medellin", "cali", "barranquilla", "bucaramanga", "cucuta", "pasto", "manizales", "caldas", "santander" ] }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `"query": {"match_all"...` clause.

For example, I have a working facet which works very similarly to yours, and I've tested extensively. I'll keep it intact so you can compare:

```
{"facets": {
  "keywords":{
    "terms":
      {"size":100,"field":"text","order":"count","exclude":["you"]}
    }
  },
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
         "and":[{
           "terms":
             {"_type":["dms","click_events"]}
           },
           {
           "range":{
             "created_at":{"from":"2013-05-26T04:00:00+00:00"}
           }
         }]
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

This successfully filters on the terms "_type":["dms","click_events"] in the filtered query.